Is there a way to export multiple Unity prefabs to multiple FBX files?
Im trying to export multiple prefabs from unity project to multiple fbx files and I dont want to do it one by one. Is there a way to export them at once?
I dont want 5 seperate prefabs to be exported as one FBX files, I need it seperate
